# Writing a file using c program in the format of table

Tags: file-io, fputs

I want to write a file in the format of table using c program.
I am using fputs to write the file. My file looks like :

```
    [sl] [Name] [School] [add]
    1 ABC DEF Dav India
    2 XYZ LLL USA
```

But, I want output file to look like :

```
    [sl]    [name]     [school]    [add]
     1      ABC DEF     DAV        INDIA
     2      XYZ         LLL        USA
```

I want to know is there something like length specifier in `fputs` like in printf so that I can change format of the file.

Comment: If you know how many spaces you are going to add, why not just create a new string of size + no. spaces. Then use a pointer to the original to iterate down the original string writing X number of spaces for each found in the original as you copy from original to new? You could also split the original string into individual words and write them back out with fprintf including the additional format you need.

Comment: Can you show how your data is current held in your program. It is a bit ambiguous whether you have and existing string you need to write or if you have `s1` `name` `school` and `add` in different variable. Show us what you have.

Comment: I dont know exact length of each word. But I know maximum length of entries  of each column. Say "name" wont have more than 50 letters . So just like printf if I give Left indentation & limit of 70 letters I will get a blank space of variable length & I can start entries of column "school" after 70 spaces . But how to do this with file

Comment: I am writing in file like :
fputs("1 ", fp);
fputs ("ABC DEF ",fp);
fputs ( "DAV ",fp);
I am showing value as an example , actually it will be stored in a variable.

Comment: If you can specify the individual parts of the string you want to write, then see Kyuubi's answer. fprintf is far more flexible for writing formatted data to a file than fputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is `fprintf`. Find out more about fprintf [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fprintf/).
It is used exactly the same way as `printf`, except it writes to a file.

## EDIT

If your string is stored in different variables, then use `fprintf` as follows :

```
fprintf(fp,"%-15s %-15s %-15s %-15s", "string 1", "string 2", "string 3", "string 4");
```

The number `15` is the fixed length that the string will use (You can change this based on the maximum string length you have or some other preference). The minus sign is for left Justified string.

Comment: fprintf won't help, He has 1 string to write with X number of spaces in the original, he wants to increase the number of spaces that exist in the original string.

Comment: There is no way to have the formatting like a table otherwise, if he has a single string. Either he can slpit the string into multiple strings first and then print them using `fprintf`.

Comment: You make a good point. I guess he will just have to post the relevant parts of his code showing the current storage of the data he wants to write out :-)

Comment: I am writing in file like : fputs("1 ", fp); fputs ("ABC DEF ",fp); fputs ( "DAV ",fp); I am showing value as an example , actually it will be stored in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

As Kyuubi specified, you will want to use `fprintf` instead of `fputs` it will cut down on the amount of code needed. The `fprintf` will write your data to a file pursuant to a format string. Since your data will be string data, you will write it out in pieces specifying %s in the format string for each piece. Take for example your `ABC DEF` words. You can use `fprintf` to write the string literals as follows:

```
fprintf (fp, "   %s    %s\n", "ABC", "DEF");
```

You can also specify the minimum field width for each word you write by specifying and integer between `%` and `s`, such as `%10s` to write '-------ABC' out with a minimum width of 10 characters. You can also place a `-` sign before the number to left align the string. For example `%-10s` to output 'ABC-------'. (the dashes are really spaces, just for illustration) The can help you separate the information you want into table form without writing out a varying number of spaces for each different fprintf call.

See 'man 3 fprintf` for all the options. There are literally 1000s of examples on the web to help.